# from "array version" of a class to the class with reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

i.e. i have "[B" but I want "B" as a Class type
I tried this:

```
String tmp = clazz.getName();
tmp=tmp.substring(1);
clazz=Class.forName(tmp);
```

but it doesn't work because I use B while it want byte I suppose

I want this code to work with every class not just byte.

Sorry for the bad explanations, I'm new to this. thanks in advance.

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not an error description. Explain what is happening and what you expect.If you get an error message share it.

Comment: You have to specify full name to the class (with package).

Answer (score 1):

For an array of primitives, `Class.getName()` will return only a single letter; that's described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

Have a look to `Class.getComponentType()`, it should solve your issue.

Comment: As derivable from the linked documentation, `substring(1)` wouldn't work for reference types either, as there's a leading ' L'  and trailing ';' to be removed.